# Are `InputStream` and `Reader` essentially the same, and are `OutputStream` and `Writer` essentially the same?

Tags: java, io

In Java, `InputStream` and `OutputStream` deal with  `byte[]`, and `Reader` and `Writer` with `char[]`.

- Do their input or output `byte[]` and `char[]` essentially have the same values?  (That is my impression, because a char and a byte in IO have the same value)
- In other words, are `InputStream` and `Reader` essentially the same, and  are `OutputStream` and `Writer` essentially the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not essentially the same, but they do the same sorts of things for different kinds of data.

[`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html) and [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html) work in *bytes*. You'd use them when dealing with non-textual information (such as an image).

[`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html) and [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Writer.html) work in *characters*. You'd use them when dealing with textual information.

So "yes" and "no". :-) `InputStream` and `Reader` are both for reading information (a stream of bytes or a stream of characters, respectively), and `OutputStream` and `Writer` are both for writing information (a stream of bytes or a stream of characters, respectively). Which you use depends on what kind of data you're dealing with. The streams are byte-oriented. The readers/writers are character-oriented.

There are bridging classes between the two kinds of data:

- [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) reads from an `InputStream` and converts bytes to characters using a `CharSet` (one provided explicitly or by name).
- [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) does the converse: Converts characters to bytes (again via a `CharSet`) and writes the bytes to an `OutputStream`.

...but most `Reader`/`Writer` subclasses read from/write to sources/destinations that are *already* character-based, and so don't deal with bytes at all. For instance, [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/StringReader.html) reads characters from a string. Since the source (the string) is *already* character-based, the `Reader` doesn't ever deal with bytes, just characters.

Comment: Thanks. Are InputStream and OutputStream effectively the same as Reader and Writer  with some charset?

Comment: @Tim - Sort of the other way around. `InputStream` + `CharSet` = `Reader`. But even that's a bit misleading. `Reader` and `Writer` may not be working from bytes at all, e.g., if the source/destination of their data is *already* character-based.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. `Reader` internally uses some `CharSet`, while `InputStream` doesn't. As far as the result is concerted, is what `InputStream` provides the same as what `Reader` with **some** `CharSet`  provides?

Comment: @Tim - No. `Reader` is an abstract class and doesn't use `CharSet`. Again, a `Reader` might be designed to read from something that's **already** character-oriented, in which case it has no need for a `CharSet`. For instance, [`CharArrayReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/CharArrayReader.html) doesn't need a `CharSet`, because what it's reading from (a `char[]`) is *already* character-based. But **if** the source of data is bytes, such as an `InputStream`, then the reader reading it will need a `CharSet` to know how to turn bytes into characters.

Comment: In fact, of the [seven direct subclasses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html) of `Reader` in the JDK, only one *requires* a `CharSet` (`InputStreamReader`), and only one other optionally accepts on (`URLReader`, you can override the charset the URL's response defines). The other five all work from data sources that are already character-based.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have the right idea. Standard classes [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) act as adapters from the byte stream interfaces to the character stream interfaces, requiring only that a Charset (typically UTF-8) is specified. That Charset will be used to convert the incoming bytes into Java's UTF-16 character type, so notably it is *not* true that the actual bytes read from an InputStream and Reader are always the same.

InputStream is typically used for reading data of any type, while Reader is only appropriate for reading text data.